# Chrome and IE driver profiles using webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My project requires certain cookies to access the application. For Firefox Driver i am using firefox profile (profile of ff which i use for manual tetsing as it has all cookies i want) to run the script. How to run the same for Chrome and IE browsers. Is there any option to get the profiles of chrome and IE browser? Thanks in Advance

Comment: IE doesn't support the notion of "profiles" like Firefox or Chrome. You'll need to create the cookies yourself, probably using the cookie API of WebDriver.

Comment: I am using following code to invoke chrome profile, But this is not working. Please let me know what i am doing wrong
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium framework\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"));
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
_driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the profile-directories, since the IE, Firefox and Chrome ones are obviously different.

It should be possible by getting the cookies and porting to Chrome or IE to with the following commands:

```py
cookies = driver.get_cookies() # to get all cookies

driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"}) # to add (port//set) cookies
```

Have look at [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/cookies/#add-cookie) for more information