# Run internet explorer as different user using Selenium

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to launch single Internet explorer instane as different user with `Selenium`. I referred to the following post but not getting anywhere.

[How can I run Internet Explorer Selenium tests as a specific domain user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045870/how-can-i-run-internet-explorer-selenium-tests-as-a-specific-domain-user)

Can you point me in the right direction how it can be achieved?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you trying to launch multiple `ie` instances with different credentials?

Comment: Hi @Saifur I want to open single ie instance as different user.

Comment: Using the same browser with 2 different selenium instances would lead to concurrency exception/error, hence is probably not implemented.  Why not open 2 different browsers, each one binding to their own selenium instance ?
However, if it is profile you are looking for:
IE doesn't support the notion of "profiles" like Firefox or Chrome. You'll need to create the cookies yourself, probably using the cookie API of WebDriver. –  Quote from JimEvans 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294254/chrome-and-ie-driver-profiles-using-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using URI authentication. For Google Chrome that behavior works without any additional changes, but for IE it blocked by default. You can unlock it by:

Set the DWORD value's value data to 1 in one of the following registry keys.

- For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry
  key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
- For the current user of the program only, set the value in the
  following registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

After that you will be able to use next URI to achieve your needs:
http://username:password@host/
If you want to provide domain name, you need encode that like http://domain%5Cusername:password@host/

> Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489